# Greek label using package pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, greek

I'm trying to set a label for a specific page in my pdf in greek.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providename}[2]{%
   \edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
   \label{#2}%
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}



\bf \nameref{lxmas}
\newcounter{inclPDFpage}



\includepdf[pages= 2,link,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{inclPDFpage}\providename{ Παράδειγμα }{kalprot}}]{christmas_songs.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is the following:

[image]

I know it seems like a simple issue but I've spent quite a few hours trying to find a solution for this and I am new in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `pdflatex` non-ascii text are actually macros (sort of), and thus you cannot just run `\edef` on them

Try using `\protected@edef` instead

BTW: `\bf` has been depreciated since 1993!